# If i remove one MongoDB collection, the space taken by that collection can be reused by MongoDB in future?

Tags: mongodb, collections

There are about 40 collections in my MongoDB database, and they are going to exhaust my disk space soon(20GB/1TB).

I plan to remove some old collections(10 of the 40), but i don't know whether the space taken by those collections can be reused by MongoDB in future?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
db.repairDatabase()
```

to free disk  space. Otherwise, **yes**, Mongo will use the space within the files in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no enough free space to run this command. db.repairDatabase() needs double space.

Comment: Will waste much time and money(Add a new disk). Any better(easy) solution?

Comment: Sorry. None which I know.

Comment: Moving to another server?

Comment: The key though is that you don't need to if you aren't also trying to add new databases. The disk space is allocated by database and not collection. So, when you delete a collection, the space is available to the other collections or new collections within that single database. Some options are explained [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/).